# Handling React re-renders with cypress

Tags: reactjs, cypress, react-select

I have two `react-select` `Select`s side-by-side. Selecting one updates state and determines the values in the second `Select`.

My `cypress` test does this:

```
// select an option in the first select - this works
cy.get('div[class*="container"]').contains('Select 1').click()
cy.get('div[class*="option"]').contains('Select 1 Option 1').click()

// select an option in the second select - this doesn't work
cy.get('div[class*="container"]').contains('Select 2').click() // <<< error occurs here
cy.get('div[class*="option"]').contains('Select 2 Option 1').click()
```

So, the option in the first `Select` is selected successfully. But the second isn't - I get this error:

```
Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.
```

I tried a `cy.wait(10)` before `get`ting the second `Select`, which, yes, is bad practice, but even so, it didn't solve the problem. How do I do this correctly?

**Edit:**

Here's an abstraction of the implementation of the `Select`s:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([
  {
    select: '', option: ''
  }
])

const options = {
  "Select 1": [
    "Select 1 Option 1",
    "Select 1 Option 2"
  ],
  "Select 2": [
    "Select 2 Option 1",
    "Select 2 Option 2"
  ]
}

return (
  {state.map((row, index) => {
    <Select
      options={Object.keys(options)}
      value={row.select}
      onValueChange={value => setState({
        ...state,
        select: value
      })}
    />
    <Select
      options={options[row.select]}
      value={row.option}
      onValueChange={value => setState({
        ...state,
        option: value
      })}
    />
  })}
)
```

Of course, `react-select` cannot accept an array of strings as `options`, so in my real implementation, I have a function that converts each string into a `{label: '', value: ''}` object, but this is not necessary for this illustration.

The idea above is that when I select the value of the first `Select`, the view is re-rendered because the `state` changes.

Comment: Can you please share the actual selects code?

Comment: Hi @gilamran, I have added some illustrative code of my implementation. The actual implementation is more complext - the Select is abstracted with custom styling and functionality, etc. - but this is representative of my actual implementation.

Comment: replace `{state.map((row, index)` with `options.map`

Answer (score 1):

it is a bit hard to guess from your abstraction, but it seems like you are not updating the value of `state.option` that sets the value of the second select. I'm not sure what your default state is, but from your snippet above cypress would not find either select, because when you do this `cy.get('div[class*="container"]').contains('Select 1')` none of the DOM elements would actually contain the matching string `Select 1` yet.

Because you mentioned the first cy command works, I'm not sure how exactly the Select is initialising, so this is a bit of a guess.

Take a look here: https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-moon-ss4z9?file=/src/App.js